# htaccess search and replace plus sign with dash

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have form with two parameters city,keyword which are passed to search.php ,after submitting it redirects to url like 
**website.com/search/lenovo+laptop+dealers/Delhi**

But i need url to be parsed without those plus signs but with a dash in url

Example: **website.com/search/lenovo-laptop-dealers/Delhi**

Code in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?keyword=([^&]+)&city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^search/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /search.php?keyword=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule "^(search)/([^+]*)\++([^+]*\+.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule "^(search)/([^+]*)\+([^+]*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=301,NE,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?keyword=([^&]+)&city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^search/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /search.php?keyword=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235042/form-submission-error-with-htaccess-rules