# Form submission error with htaccess rules

Tags: forms, .htaccess, redirect

I have form on home page index.php which passes variables to page search.php after submission url looks like
**justdlal.com/search/Computer-Hardware/Delhi**

In the same page i have same form with two inputs city and keyword but after submitting it must go to url like
**justdlal.com/search/laptop/Delhi**
but instead it is appending search query to current url like
**justdlal.com/search/Computer-Hardware/search.php?keyword=laptop&city=Delhi**

My htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "^(search)/([^+]*)\++([^+]*\+.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule "^(search)/([^+]*)\+([^+]*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=301,NE,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?keyword=([^&]+)&city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^search/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /search.php?keyword=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "^(search)/([^+]*)\++([^+]*\+.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule "^(search)/([^+]*)\+([^+]*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=301,NE,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?keyword=([^&]+)&city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^search/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /search.php?keyword=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: form action with slash worked out...<form action="/search.php"

Comment: ya i didnt modified htaccess ,when i have put "/search.php" in form action instead of "search.php" it worked normally